# Is it necessary to install Typescript before installing Angular?

Tags: angular

According to an Angular book (updated to Angular 9) that I'm currently reading, the Angular installation steps are:

1. Installing Node.js
2. Installing Typescript: npm install -g typescript
3. Installing Typings: npm install --save @types/npm
4. Installing Angular CLI: npm install -g @angular/cli

Then, I went to the [official Angular setup documentation](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local) and the Typescript and Typings installation are not included.

Do you know what is the purpose of those installations? Is it a deprecated way of installing Angular? The latest Angular version already include those packages?

I made some research but I couldn't find an answer to these questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Not necessary to install typescript.

Comment: The only thing necessary is node.js. Not even @angular/cli, you can put that as a devDependency

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing necessary is Node.js. There is no benefit of installing typescript. This will all be handled by the Angular CLI. They require a specific typescript version, which is usually one version behind the actual latest version of typescript.

My advice, stick to the excellent guides on angular.io. It's your safest bet.

Comment: the cli is pretty useful / recommended for starting new angular projects though

Comment: Thanks Poul and @bryan. I see that it is not strictly necessary to install Typescript but, will I have any benefit of doing it? I can imagine that the answer will be: "not for an entry level programmer", but I'm interested on any additional information or clue to continue my research, this is a completely new world for me. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t know of any benefit to globally installing typescript or npm typings to install or run an angular app. There are many benefits to using the cli to all levels of programmer.

Comment: @bryan60 I was talking about installing the cli as a global package. That's also not necessary. It's actually recommended to keep it as a local package in your project

Comment: @Gustavo there is no benefit of installing typescript. This will all be handled by the angular cli. They require a specific typescript version, which is usually one version behind the actual latest version of typescript.

Comment: You can’t use ng new if it’s not global? I’ve never seen them recommend keeping it local? Have a link?

Comment: @bryan60 It's actually a relatively old recommendation. It's particularly useful when sharing your project with other contributors. This way you can be sure they will always use the same angular/cli version. Nevertheless, it seems like that since a couple versions ago they actually delegate the command you write to your locally installed version if it exists. So that's nice :) It is however still recommended to have a local version in your package.json for the reason I stated above. About the `ng new`, if you don't have a global version, you can just do `npx ng new`

Comment: I know it’s a good practice to have a locally installed version to keep consistency. I’ve never seen it recommended to be ONLY local as I do believe the global install is practically required. I still don’t understand at all how if I’m doing a first time angular install for a brand new project, how I’m going to start the project without a global cli install? Are you suggesting I first do an npm init and then install the cli locally and then run the new commands? That would feel extra compared to keeping a global install

Comment: @bryan60 you are absolutely right. I've been working too long with a mono repo with one angular version :D